# AWS: Serve up website from private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

I'm unable to get from the internet to a web page hosted on my server in a private subnet.

Using this: [How can I place a Webserver in a private subnet in AWS and open it to the world on port 80](https://serverfault.com/questions/724149/how-can-i-place-a-webserver-in-a-private-subnet-in-aws-and-open-it-to-the-world) as a guide, I've got the following configuration in place:

- VPC w/ 1 public and private subnet (both are in same AZ).
- Public subnet has route table with local and IGW routes
- Private subnet has route table with local and NAT Gateway routes
- EC2 Instance deployed in private subnet serving up static HTML pages
- Confirmed EC2 instance can get out to internet
- ELB pointing (ports 80/443) to EC2 private instance
- (For testing) ELB security group and EC2 SG are set to allow all inbound/outbound traffic
- ELB health check is good
- R53 (A record) for testing subdomain which points to my ELB

With everything supposedly operational and open, I can't determine why the page isn't served back to the user.  Chrome just spins and Firefox says the connection was reset.  Any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Which subnet did you place the ELB itself on?  It needs to be on the public subnet, not private.

Comment: ELB is in my public subnet.

Comment: What happens if you go to the elastic beanstalk URL provided?

Comment: Route 53 A record pointing to ELB is wrong. It should be a CNAME or an Alias.

Comment: Attempting to go to the ELB URL yields a "No Data Received" error in Chrome.  The A record in R53 is set as an alias target of the ELB...and doesn't work.  If I switch it to CNAME, it doesn't allow the ELB to be set as the target.

Answer (score 1):

Following this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-groups.html#elb-vpc-security-groups , specifically the section: Internet-facing Load Balancer: Recommended Rules

I needed to update the outbound rules of my ELB to use my instance security group.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to put the ELB in a subnet that has a route to an Internet Gateway (Your public subnet).  Here's an AWS forums post with more details: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=415184&#415184

Comment: My ELB is in my public subnet which has a route to the IGW. Thanks.